# Why is std::deque not a vector with memory reserved before index 0?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, deque

As far as I understand, the motivation behind deque is to provide a random-access container with efficient `push_front`.

Commonly cited advantages of vector compared to deque include faster traversal and `at()`, but mostly its C compatibility, as it guarantees contiguous memory. Deque does not, since it is a collection of chunks of memory, each holding a number of values.

I'm confused. Why is not deque built like a vector but with memory reserved before index `0` in addition to the memory reserved after index `size-1` ? This would guarantee contiguous memory, enable efficient `push_front` and even avoid the additional indirection when dereferencing iterators.

To minimize shifting during insertion, the contained values to be shifted would depend on the insertion point. If inserting at index `n` being before `size()/2`, shift values up to `n` left. Otherwise shift right the values after `n`.

What did I miss that is so important that deque is a collection of arrays of values and not one big array ?

Comment: Amortized costs, maybe? Fast `push_front` isn't the only requirement for `deque`

Comment: And how much memory would you reserve? 1KB, 10KB, 1M, 1GB, 24GB? Whatever you do, someone will be complaining that it's either too much or not enough...

Comment: Afaik that's the way Qt implements its QList

Comment: @MatsPetersson Well same as `vector`. I remember from an inside the STL video from the STL guy, Microsoft grows its vectors 1,5x each time. Put 0,5 extra size before too and you get a nice round growth factor of 2.

Comment: There is nothing preventing you from implementing your own variant that way, but I believe there is a logic behind the way it is implemented, and that is to allocate as needed at both ends, with some "extra factor" to avoid having to allocate every single addition [that gets expensive].

Comment: @WhozCraig: *"deque will never invalidate currently established iterators or pointers when an insertion is performed"* -- How do you gather that? The only guarantee I can see in the standard is that *references* will not be invalidated when insertion is performed at one of the ends, but iterators will be invalidated by any insertion.  And references will still be invalidated by insertions not at the ends.

Comment: @WhozCraig: That's accurate, mostly(you can get references directly from a few other member functions), but, I guess I don't understand where you're going with it. It's perfectly possible to design an iterator in such a way that you can get a reference from it, then something can happen that causes the iterator to become invalid, but the reference still remains valid. As a simple example, the iterator might simply hold a pointer to the container, and an integer to indicate an offset from the beginning of the container. So when you add something to the beginning, that offset is no longer valid.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You're not only correct, you're correct at the top of the standards voice, which I just checked to learn more. In C++11 §23.3.3.4p1, *"An insertion in the middle of the deque invalidates all the iterators and references to elements of the deque. An insertion at either end of the deque invalidates all the iterators to the deque, but has no effect on the validity of references to elements of the deque"* So you're  *very* right. I need to delete my prior comment as an service to the community. Thank you *very* much for the example and the prod to look further.

Comment: If `vector` and `deque` would be more similar then in would be mostly pointless to have both... So it make sense that different containers have different characteristics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deque#Implementations), what you're describing is indeed one possible implementation, at least in general.

However, the C++ standard imposes requirements that essentially prohibit this as an implementation for `std::deque`; [deque.modifiers] states:

> An insertion at either end of the deque ... has no effect on the validity of references to elements of the deque.

(Thanks to @BenjaminLindley!)

Comment: I STFW for an answer, but Wikipedia doesn't usually come to my mind for such topics (:

Comment: 23.3.3.4/1 and /4 says that insertion or removal at the ends of the deque shall not invalidate references.  That wouldn't be possible if the deque worked like this. (I said iterators before, but it's only references)

Comment: So implementations that rely on contiguous memory with reallocs are not standard-compliant ? I guess other implementations could provide C compatibility with a `c_array` function, much like `string::c_str`, that would repack all the chunks in one big one and be invalidated by inserts.